# adding string numbers together ruby

Tags: ruby, string, integer, gets, puts

I have made this program which counts characters in your name.

```
puts 'What is your first name?'
forename = gets.chomp
puts 'what is your middle name?'
middlename = gets.chomp
puts 'what is your surname?'
surname = gets.chomp
puts 'Did you know there are ' + forename.length.to_s + middlename.length.to_s + surname.length.to_s + ' characters in your name?'
```

However this adds the numbers next to each other to equal 555 instead of 15.
I cant convert the lengths to integers as I won't be able to add the string of text before.

Comment: `+`(add) on a string does concat the strings. You are converting the numbers to string before adding(concatenating) them, instead use string interpolation `puts "Did you know there are  #{forename.length + middlename.length + surname.length}  characters in your name?"`, if you want to do it your way then you can do `puts 'Did you know there are ' + (forename.length + middlename.length + surname.length).to_s + ' characters in your name?'`

Comment: Thank you for this, the second part is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
puts 'What is your first name?'
forename = gets.chomp
puts 'what is your middle name?'
middlename = gets.chomp
puts 'what is your surname?'
surname = gets.chomp
name_length = [forename,middlename,surname].map(&:length).inject(:+)
puts 'Did you know there are ' + name_length + ' characters in your name?'
```

OR simply without the #to_s. With #to_s you are converting numbers back to string and concatenating string.

```
puts 'What is your first name?'
forename = gets.chomp
puts 'what is your middle name?'
middlename = gets.chomp
puts 'what is your surname?'
surname = gets.chomp
puts 'Did you know there are ' + forename.length + middlename.length + surname.length + ' characters in your name?'
```

Comment: mike name_length = [forename,middlename,surname].map(&:length).inject(:+) that will create an array and  then map it and then concat the strings isnt necessary, it's better solution your second one (and as you said simple)